# PySpark select top N Rows from each group

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to choose a N rows randomly for each category of a column in a data frame. Let's say the column is the 'color' and N is 5. Then I'd want to choose 5 items for each of the colors.

The usual way of doing this is something like this

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number

# Define a random key that can be used to sort by
df = df.select("*", rand().alias(key))         
    # Sort the rows within each color by the key
    # Simultaneously enumerate the sorted rows
    .withColumn(num, row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(color).orderBy(key)))
    # Choose only N items for each category   
    .where(f"{num} <= {N}")
    # Drop key column
    .drop(key)
```

But orderBy blows up with an out of memory error on large dataframes. I'm considering using sort to work around this. Context: 'orderBy' runs on a single executor and guarantees total order while sort uses several partitions. I'm ok with the approximate nature of sort as I'm using this to select random subsets anyway.

I can't just replace orderBy as sort can't be used with row_number in a window as above.

Any pointers appreciated.

**References:**

- Code snippet from https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-retrieve-top-n-from-each-group-of-dataframe/
- Comparison between orderBy and sort from https://towardsdatascience.com/sort-vs-orderby-in-spark-8a912475390

Comment: Have you considered `df.sample`? It only does fractions, but you could do a small fraction and then apply your method to the sample.

Comment: If u want top N then computation is reqd. May be more partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use what they call a 'salt' to redistribute the data, and make it smaller. (Here I'm going to split your colour column into `floor(key*8)`  before randomly sorting it, but that's just a guess that it will work for you and really could be increased if you wish) Then you can re-window as you do today without the salt.

```
# Define a random key that can be used to sort by and salt by
df = df.select("*", rand().alias(key))         
    # Sort the rows within each color by the key
    # Simultaneously enumerate the sorted rows
    .withColumn(num, row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(color,floor(key*8)).orderBy(key)))#divides the data into smaller by a factor of 8 chunks using the salt
    # Choose only N items for each category   
    .where(f"{num} <= {N}")
    .drop( num )
    .withColumn(num, row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(color).orderBy(key)))
    .where(f"{num} <= {N}")
    # Drop key column
    .drop(key)
```

I do think you should look into `df.sample` as it's made to do this type of thing but if you like your logic as is this will work for you.

Comment: If you found my comment helpful please upvote. If you are comfortable marking it as the answer I'd appreciate you marking it so when you have time.